# How to change the default bullet style in Powerpoint 2013?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

How do I set a custom bullet style as default, which can be used anytime.

OS - Win 7 (64)
Office 2013

This is the default bullet list:

[image: Default List]

This is the custom bullet style I have created:

[image: Custom List]

How to ensure that the custom style is available when I work with any themes or other presentations?